# How to get the children of an object in Firebase database?

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to alert this array using Firebase Realtime Database:

```
  "discuss" : {
    "taj" : {
      "20200809" : {
        "comment" : "first comment",
        "full_date" : "2020/08/09"
      }
    }
  }
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
        data.val().children.forEach(children => {
            alert(children.comment)
        });
```

But came out with nothing.
Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get `comment` from the database, then try the following:

```
 let ref = firebase.database().ref("dicuss");

ref.child("taj").on("value", function(snapshot) {
 snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
  var comment = childSnapshot.val().comment;
  console.log(comment);
 });
});
```

Add a reference to the node `taj` then iterate and retrieve the `comment` attribute.

Check the docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't know about the childSnapshot and the for some reason did not catch the Firebase documentation. Will do right now.